# String to array conversion in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript object:

```js
{
    "answers": "[0,0,0,0,1]"
}
```

I want to convert the `answer` string to an `array`:

```js
var array = [0,0,0,0,1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Json.parse()`function for that.

```js
const answers = "[0,0,0,0,1]"
console.log(JSON.parse(answers))
```